# Android can't connect to socket

Tags: android, sockets

I am working on a Program that is going to connect to a lite coin miner via socket. The port is 4028 the ip is 192.168.0.41, but I cant even make a socket so I have written a very simple test program to try to better trouble shoot this.

```
package atherlrix2.cgminermonitor;
import java.net.Socket;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView hash = new TextView(this);
    hash.setTextSize(175);
    hash.setText("null");
            try {
             int port = 4028;
             Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.41", port);
             hash.setText("hhhhh");
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
     }
}
```

So almost this exact code works on java. I do not under stand why it wouldn't work here.
I have added these lines to my XML to try to give it permissions or something.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

I have even turned of my mobile data and made sure I am connected to WiFi.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? I smell a NetworkOnMainThreadException...

Comment: I don't really know how to find out Would you be willing to help me figure how to find errors i just started programming android 2 days ago.

Comment: Don't catch and ignore exceptions. Log them. See the log for helpful exception stacktrace information.

Comment: Yes that is the exception.

Comment: So to fix this I would have to put this in a new thread and use a handler with messages right???

Comment: `AsyncTask` is probably the easiest way to offload processing to a background thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)